# Background Blur - CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I try to make this background Blur like this image so I'd like to know if I can do it using CSS3 only or I need to use Javascript & Jquery:

And if I will use css only How to make the blur is responsive.

[image]

**Here my simple code:**

```css
#bg{
  background-image: url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149079039538851.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#bg {
  background-position: center top;
  padding: 70px 90px 120px 90px;
}

#search-container {
  position: relative;
}

#search-bg {
  /* Absolutely position it, but stretch it to all four corners, then put it just behind #search's z-index */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  /* Pull the background 70px higher to the same place as #bg's */
  /*background-position: center -70px;*/
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}

#search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(34,34,34,0.75);
}
#search h2{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
        <div id="search-container">
            <div id="search-bg"></div>
            <div id="search">
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**To blur all the background**

You can't easily attach effect to a background image. You should blur it with a software and set it as background-image.

You can have a blur background in css with a div placing behind yout site content, and blur this div like that :
http://codepen.io/aniketpant/pen/DsEve

```
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="content"> Your text </div>
```

---

**Blur behind an element**

You can get this result with CSS3 backdrop filter:

https://webkit.org/blog/3632/introducing-backdrop-filters/

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: No problems, don't forget to check my answer if you consider it as a good answer :) (The checkmark)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `background-attachment:fixed;` and set it **also** in the blured container , `background-attachment`  is there to set both bg on the same spot, one can be blured.

example with a pseudo instead extra div:

```css
#bg {
  background-image: url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149079039538851.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center top;
  padding: 70px 90px 120px 90px;
}

#search-container {
  position: relative;
}

#search-container:before {/* add same bg-image with same backgrounds values to match main container */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-03/149079039538851.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;/* make it match #bg position and size */
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
  display:flex;
}

#search h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="search-container">
    <div id="search">
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: render from FF 52]

Comment: I think you're on the right path, GCyrillus, but why are you setting a background-image on the :before? It won't look correct, depending on your resolution. Rather than set any background-image, you can just set the background-color to an rgba value (or just manually set the opacity) and achieve a better effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/osou43hz/

Comment: @jas7457 , you need also the same image in the background **to blur it** . position:fixed is used for both backgrounds so they match on same area. If it was only a matter of opacity, an rgba() background-color is plenty enough and pseudo is not needed. The problem is to have the bg being blured only where the #search box stands. Your fiddle does not blur the background image of the main container ;) // just made a codepen to play with : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PpVzRz

Comment: Resize your window so that it is < 700px. You'll see that your solution is no longer valid

Comment: @jas7457 wich browser ?  this is what i get in FF https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVRGg.jpg